# Trying to get info from table, getting resource values

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to get data from a table column that has a corresponding ID, but when I try to get an ID it gives me a 'resource ID'. My column ID holds INTs, and I found that if I add or subtract to the resource ID i get a number so I tried adding then subtracting 1, but it still isn't working.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("blog") or die(mysql_error());
$strSQL = "SELECT id FROM blogtable ORDER BY id DESC";
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
$artID = $rs-1+1;//So if I don't do this, I get resource ID#'#'
?>
```

This code is on the same page, but in a separate container.

```
<?php
$getArticle = "SELECT title FROM blogtable Where id = '$artID'";
$selectedArticle = mysql_query($getArticle);
echo $selectedArticle;
?>
```

I was hoping this would get me the text from my title column, but it just gives me another resource id.

Comment: You should fetch a row from the result set. Check the manual on mysql and go straight to PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$result = mysql_fetch_object($rs);   
$artID = $result->id;
```

...

```
$selectedArticle = mysql_query($getArticle);
$res = mysql_fetch_object($selectedArticle);
echo $res->title;
```

But i will recommende using PDO or mysqli functions since mysql_ functions will become obsolete.

mysqli examples: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

or

PDO tutorials: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` gives you resource id. If you want to get your ID;

```
$id = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs)) {
    $id =  $row['ID'];  
}
```

Or

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($rs);
```

and get id from `$row` array